Serial port fail on High temperature
I have an issue with this RS232 buffer. My circuit consists of an STM32 MCU with this buffer:

I am conducting tests in a thermal chamber, the MCU send a status message on UART every second, I notice that every time the temperature rises above 60°C, incomprehensible characters start coming out of the serial port. Both the MCU and the MAX232 can operate at temperatures well above 60°C, so I am trying to understand what is happening.
Could it be that the problem is the filter, which at that temperature assumes an impedance that destroys the signal? Or what else could it be?

Can you use a logic analyser or oscilloscope to capture the transmitted messages at the higher temperatures? Such a capture would help to identify if the bit times of the UART characters change their width at higher temperatures, which could point at the clock frequency used to generate the UART baud rate being sensitive to temperature.

Please edit the question to add oscilloscope traces of the "good" vs "incomprehensible" output that you observe.

Show scope traces of MCU UART signal as well as RS232 output. Show them on the same scope image for ease of comparison. Please also provide datasheet link to D3/D4

The filter is (just) within the permissible 2.5nF capacitive loading for RS-232D. An oscilloscope is what is needed here- we can't be sure without that. Chances are very good that if it fails at 60'C it's marginal at room temperature.

What speed is the serial?  What are you using for your clock source?

You can try to bypass the line filter components (L3, L4, and associated capacitors) and test the circuit again at elevated temperatures. This will help confirm if the filter is indeed affecting the signal.

I think you are focusing on the wrong thing. Which exact STM32 model you are using and are you using one of the internal clock sources?

Thank you, next week i'll do the test with oscilloscope, and share with you the waveform. Regarding the MCU is a STM32H745IIT6 and the clock source is a ECS-2016MVQ-250-BS-TR

I have done many tests with the oscilloscope in a thermal chamber, and gradually increasing the temperature I have not noticed any malfunction.
However, I have noticed that if I vary the temperature very quickly, for example if I go from 30 to 60 degrees in 1 minute, then the data begins to no longer come out correctly. Is this normal behavior? Do the components have a limit on the speed of temperature variation that they can withstand?
